# Windows Console application crashes at the end abruptly

Tags: c#, crash

I've an application in C# which works and ends abruptly at the end saying

> "ABC.exe has stopped working" A problem caused the program to stop
>   working correctly. Windows will close the program .. . . . . .

If I put breakpoints and execute line by line till end of main(), it works perfectly without any issues. 
Could not rootcause this issue to where it occurs?

could you please guide what to be done in such cases? I'm using VS2012 and Win8 OS.

Comment: It would help if we had some code to work with. Reduce your application to the minimum required to repeat the problem and edit it into your question.

Comment: Are you using multi-threading in your application?  One possible cause is an unhandled exception on a background thread.

Comment: No I'm not using MultiThreading for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [break when an exception is thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)

Comment: This helped me to get through. I had an exception in Destructor. Thanks a bunch for the help.